# Site Search for POST-Based Search Engines

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Using google tag manager and GA. Need to track search strings.

We don't have a query string or URL to use/key on. The search term is hidden in the form post and does not appear in the URL or query string.

How do I push search terms to GA so I can fake the search tracking?

Something like:

```
dataLayer.push({ 'page': 'search.aspx', 'keyword': 'my_search_term_here' });
```

From google dev docs here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en

```
They recommend using: ga('send', 'pageview', '/search_results.php?q=keyword');
```

However ga keep coming up as undefined. We are using tag manager to inject universal analytics into our site. Is there a UA equiavalent?

Answer (score 0):

You could track site searches as a GA event. Whenever a search is submitted, you need to push an event to the dataLayer, along with the other parameters you have indicated:

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'search submitted',
   'page': 'search.aspx',
   'keyword': 'my_search_term_here'
})
```

Your tag is then triggered to fire on that event. You could pass any of your specific search values into that event tag. The key here being the "event" key that gets pushed as well. You probably don't need a 'page' key as that can come from your auto-event variables in GTM.

To track the search term into the search terms report, you would need to modify the pageview tag and overwrite the existing "page" value so as to include a formatted string that would include a search query parameter, for example:

```
page: /search.aspx?q=my_search_term_here
```

You would need to set up a variable that captures the entered search term and feeds that into the modified page value. You can find more info on how to do this here: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/fix-ga-site-search-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, this will track it as an event. How would I push that data so it shows up in the "site search" section of GA?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include that aspect as well of tracking into search terms report.